C debugger Not able to Print or take Input when in debugger mode is On
in .vscode Folder there is 4 files :.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json .vscode/extensions.json .vscode/launch.json .vscode/tasks.json:
My lanch.json:
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "C/C++: gcc.exe build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                    "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file"
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}

_______________________________
task.json :
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}

c_cpp_properties.json:
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.22621.0",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64",
            "compilerPath": "C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}

Vs Code Image<- See the Vs Code Image
code :
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
int i;
scanf("%d", &i);
printf("You entered: %d\n", i);
return 0;
}

Terminal:

PS C:\Users\***\OneDrive\Documents\INTERVIEW PREP\DSA and Small Learnings>  & 'c:\Users\****\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.23.0-win32-x64\debugAdapters\bin\WindowsDebugLauncher.exe' '--stdin=Microsoft-MIEngine-In-caznmueg.sx2' '--stdout=Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-kpfaclzx.m3o' '--stderr=Microsoft-MIEngine-Error-nq1rgwan.vxy' '--pid=Microsoft-MIEngine-Pid-d12jsuyv.lf0' '--dbgExe=C:\MinGW\bin\gdb.exe' '--interpreter=mi' 
 

When I press F5, means i debug my C code, it not prints anything or neither take any inputs if scanf is there, if debugger is at scanf , and if i press F10 , then as shown in picture, Nothing happens. I can Only hover and see the variable value.  I have installed ```C/C++``` set up, ```codeLLB``` and code runner extensions, as well.
Also, If I not put debugger at scanf function: it waits for input ,but when i write something and hit enter, nothing happens, also the debugger not allow to step next step...And after that if i stop the debugger, then what ever i wrote in terminal ,shows there immediately. Example: if i wrote fffff and then stop debugger then that word executes in terminal!
means the inputs are appended in cmd after i stop debugger.
